# Remove highly similar Date columns from dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a very messy dataframe, filled with NAs and with far too many date columns, that I must use for a machine learning / prediction problem. The dataframe has many columns of class date that have similar, but not identical, information. I would like to find a way algorithmically to:

- identify very similar columns
- choose which of the two columns to remove, once a similar pair is identified

I have a very naive approach currently, and have a test dataframe below to share my approach with:

```
mydf = structure(list(last.activity.date = structure(c(17407, NA, NA, 
17333, 17338, 17357, 17388, 17350, NA, 17322, 17406, NA, 17336, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17323, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17375, 17401, 17325, 
17400, NA, NA, 17380), class = "Date"), last.contacted = structure(c(17406, 
NA, NA, 17333, NA, 17357, 17388, 17350, NA, 17322, 17406, NA, 
17336, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17354, 17401, 
17325, 17382, NA, NA, 17380), class = "Date"), create.date = structure(c(17319, 
17319, 17319, 17319, 17319, 17319, 17319, 17319, 17320, 17319, 
17320, 17320, 17320, 17320, 17321, 17321, 17322, 17322, 17322, 
17322, 17322, 17322, 17322, 17322, 17322, 17323, 17322, 17323, 
17323, 17323), class = "Date"), became.a.subscriber.date = structure(c(17319, 
17319, NA, 17346, NA, 17319, 17319, 17319, 17320, 17319, NA, 
17320, 17346, 17320, 17321, 17321, 17322, 17322, 17346, 17322, 
17322, 17322, 17322, 17322, NA, 17323, 17322, 17323, 17323, 17323
), class = "Date"), first.email.send.date = structure(c(17319, 
17319, 17319, 17319, 17320, 17319, 17319, 17319, 17320, 17319, 
17320, 17320, 17320, 17320, 17321, 17321, 17322, 17322, 17322, 
17322, 17322, 17322, 17322, 17322, 17322, 17323, 17322, 17323, 
17323, 17323), class = "Date"), last.email.click.date = structure(c(17320, 
NA, 17357, 17338, 17323, 17345, 17358, 17350, NA, 17319, NA, 
17345, 17336, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17327, 17328, NA, NA, NA, 17359, 
17379, 17325, 17323, NA, NA, 17379), class = "Date")), .Names = c("last.activity.date", 
"last.contacted", "create.date", "became.a.subscriber.date", 
"first.email.send.date", "last.email.click.date"), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

What my current approach is is to do a nested for loop, grabbing two columns each time, and checking what % of the values are similar when both columns are NA, and saving the output into a similarity matrix. Here is my approach:

```
sim.df = matrix(data = 0, nrow = ncol(mydf), ncol = ncol(mydf))

for(i in 1:ncol(mydf)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(mydf)) {

    # skip diagonal elements
    if(i == j) { sim.df[i,j] = 0; next }

    # grab two columns
    a = mydf[,i]
    b = mydf[,j]

    # compute similarity accuracy when both columns are not NA
    idxs = !is.na(a) & !is.na(b)
    sims = sum(a[idxs] == b[idxs]) / sum(idxs)

    # update output matrix    
    sim.df[i,j] = sims
  }
}
```

and here is my sim.df output from this approach:

```
round(sim.df, 3)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
[1,] 0.000 0.769 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.214
[2,] 0.769 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.250
[3,] 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.885 0.967 0.059
[4,] 0.000 0.000 0.885 0.000 0.885 0.071
[5,] 0.000 0.000 0.967 0.885 0.000 0.059
[6,] 0.214 0.250 0.059 0.071 0.059 0.000
```

In this case, columns 1 and 2 are similar, as are 3-5, while column 6 is fairly unique compared to the rest. For columns 1 and 2, they are similar but column 2 has several NAs where column 1 has values, but not vice versa, so I would probably prefer to keep column 1. In the case of columns 3-5, column 4 has NAs whereas 3 and 5 don't, and I would probably be indifferent between choosing between the two. I would also keep column 6.

My actual dataframe has ~40 date columns, and it is difficult to make these simply keep / remove column inferences with a 40x40 similarity matrix. I am looking for a better approach to this problem.

Thanks!